# Is there any way to move the camera with a mock hmd VR SDK and move the camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk

So i am building a homemade "oculus quest" and have some arduino stuff in my mind right now a I can't seem to move the main camera when I have The Mock HMD XR SDK applied in my project settings. I need a SDK that produces the same result as Mock HMD but allows you to move the camera or find a way to move the camera. Whenever I research I can't find anything not even unity documentation even tho its part of unity at least 2019.2.15. Pls help.[Mock Hmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMS9G.png)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for reviving, but maybe you still want to look into this.

It's possible to build your own custom XR Plugin, that's probably what you should try to do. I sucessfully did a VR Simulator for the Asset Store this way, however it doesn't include rendering. So you are only able to move and control headset and controllers. However you are able to use multiple XR providers simultaneously by discovering subsystems at runtime and activate them as you want. Have a look here: https://docs.unity.cn/Manual/xrsdk-runtime-discovery.html.

Thats also why u can't control your camera manually, as MockHMD provides simulated head tracking and overrides any changes made to the tracked Pose driver.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I read this post too late for you: but have a look on Vive Input Utility. They have a Simulator, and they support not only HTC, also Oculus, Cardboard etc.

Here's the repo: [GitHub VIU](https://github.com/ViveSoftware/ViveInputUtility-Unity)